# Remove vertical scrolling on mobile without using overflow

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, scrollbar, overflow

Is there a way to remove that small vertical scroll on the mobile view of webpages without using overflow?

I know the normal way is to just add: `overflow-x: hidden;` but, I also have an element with sticky positioning `position: sticky;` which doesn't work anymore when overflow is applied to the parent elements. So is there a way i can get the same effect but without using overflow?

```css
html,body{
  overflow-x: hidden; /* ADDIND THIS SOLVES THE VERTICAL SCROLL ISSUE BUT BREAKS THE STICKY DIV BELOW */
}

div.header-fixed {
 position: -webkit-sticky; /* Apple */
 position: sticky;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #202020;
 padding: 5px;
 top: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="read comments in css">
<title>scroll</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="header-fixed" id="fixed-header">
</div>
<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a
<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a
</body>
```

Comment: Are you using a container ? Some Code example or a fiddle will help us to give you a solution

Comment: i added a basic example of the issue

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the vertical scrollbar with the `::-webkit-scrollbar` pseudo-element, but it not works in firefox browser:

```css
body{
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scrollbar-width: none; /* Firefox ? */
  -ms-overflow-style: none; /* IE, Edge */
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none; /* Chrome, Opera, Safari */
}

div.header-fixed {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  /* Apple */
  position: sticky;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #202020;
  padding: 5px;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="description" content="CSCB20 Course Website">
  <title>scroll</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header-fixed" id="fixed-header">
  </div>
  <br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a
  <br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a
</body>
```

An other option is to use containers, the child container's width is more than the parent container's, so the scrollbar will be hidden:

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 75vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.child {
  width: 105%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

div.header-fixed {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  /* Apple */
  position: sticky;
  background-color: #202020;
  padding: 5px;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="description" content="CSCB20 Course Website">
  <title>scroll</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header-fixed" id="fixed-header">
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child"> <br>a<br>a<br>b<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>b<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>b<br>a<br>a
      <br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>b<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>b<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>b<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: this hides the scrollbar but the page will still scroll to the left and right when on mobile touchscreen and when shift scrolling. when using `overflow-x: hidden;` however it works the way i want but it breaks the stick div